# Difference of Ordered Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics, beta-function

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be $n$ random variables distributed uniform(0,1) and $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},..., X_{(n)}$ be the ordered statistics of $X_1,...,X_n$ such that:

$X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} < ... < X_{(n)}$

$X_{(1)} = min(X_1,...,X_n)$

$X_{(n)} = max(X_1,...,X_n)$

I know that these variables are distributed:

$X_{(i)} \sim Beta(i, n+1-i)$

I am looking to find the distribution of the difference of consecutive ordered statistics:

$Y_{i+1,i} = X_{(i+1)} - X_{(i)}$

in order to calculate the total probability:

$p = P(Y_{2,1} < d_{2,1} \cap Y_{3,2} < d_{3,2} \cap ... \cap Y_{n,n-1} < d_{n,n-1})$

Where $d_{i+1,i}$ are some given distances

This proof, [Difference of order statistics in a sample of uniform random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68749/difference-of-order-statistics-in-a-sample-of-uniform-random-variables), suggests that the distribution of $Y_{i+1,i}$ is

$Y_{i+1,i} \sim Beta(1,n)$

This suggests that the events in the probability, $p$, above are independent... is this true?

Comment: Please check the meaning of "to suggest". Your first "suggests" should read "proves", and the "suggests that" should read "says nothing about whether". By the way, your Ys are rather obviously *negatively* correlated.

Comment: @Did. See simulation demo of negative correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your subscripts on the $Y$'s are backwards.
Your individual distributions for the order statistics and
their differences seem correct. However, your assertion
about independence of the $Y$'s seems counter-intuitive
to me, and does not turn out to be true in the simple
simulation below (using R), for $n = 5$ and the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th
order statistics. All four such differences in neighboring order statistics
are constrained to add to the range of the five observations.

I will leave it to you to fix your notation, decide whether
I correctly guessed your intentions, and investigate association
between differences in order statistics.

```
 n = 5;  h = 2;  j = 3;  k = 4
 m = 10^4;  xh = xj = xk = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   x = sort(runif(n));  xh[i] = x[h];  xj[i] = x[j];  xk[i] = x[k] }

 ks.test(xh, "pbeta", h, n+1-h)
 ##  One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test  (data:  xh) 
 ## D = 0.0098, p-value = 0.2905 # Consistent with Beta(2,4)
 ## alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 ks.test(xj, "pbeta", j, n+1-j)
 ## One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test  (data:  xj) 
 ## D = 0.0066, p-value = 0.7684  # Consistent with Beta(3,3)
 ## alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 ks.test(xk, "pbeta", k, n+1-k)
 ## One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test  (data:  xk)
 ## D = 0.0057, p-value = 0.902  # Consistent with Beta(4, 2)
 ## alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 yhj = xj - xh;  yjk = xk - xj
 ks.test(yhj, "pbeta", 1, n)
 ## One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test  (data:  yhj)
 ## D = 0.0095, p-value = 0.3302  # Consistent with Beta(1, 5)
 ## alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 ks.test(yjk, "pbeta", 1, n)  
 ## One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test  (data:  yjk)
 ## D = 0.0076, p-value = 0.6164  # Consistent with Beta(1, 5)
 ## alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 cor(yhj, yjk)
 ## -0.199315  # NOT consistent with 0 correlation implied by independence
```

Note: The method of simulation is certainly not optimal for speed, but
may be more transparent than an optimal one for those unfamiliar with R programming.

Answer (score 0):

They can't be independent, since they sum up to $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}\leq 1$. So if you know for example that $Y_{2,1}$ is 0.5, you get that $Y_{3,2}+Y_{4,3}+...+Y_{n,n-1}\leq 0.5$, which implies that $Y_{3,2}\leq 0.5$. This can't be a beta distribution.