# Deriving distribution of the difference of the order statistics for uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $U_{1}, \, ... \, ,U_{n}$ be a random sample of uniform random variables $U_i \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. Let $U_{(1)}, \, ... \, , U_{(n)}$ be the order statistics of the sample. The goal is to prove that:

$$
W = U_{(s)}-U_{(r)} \sim \textrm{Beta}(s-r, \, n - s + r +1) \qquad 1 \leq r < s \leq n
$$

How do I prove this? I have tried the method of using the joint pdf and condensing it to the pdf of the difference to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Easy to get tangled up in notation for the most general case. Suggest you start with $n = 3$ and try to get dist'ns of max minus min and max minus median. Your approach using the joint PDF of order statistics is correct. // BTW, answ to these two are BETA(2,2) and BETA(1,3), respectively.

Comment: This is a standard topic and it is competently discussed in some _noncommercial_ items on the internet: Google 'order statistics uniform'. You might look at Wikipedia 'Order Statistics' (sec 2.1.2) and 'Uniform distribution' (sec 2.2). Also several university lecture notes seem directly relevant for derivations, especially one from Duke U.

Comment: And see @Did's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68749/difference-of-order-statistics-in-a-sample-of-uniform-random-variables?rq=1), along with other links in the 'Related' column to the right on your screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of order statistics in a sample of uniform random variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68749/difference-of-order-statistics-in-a-sample-of-uniform-random-variables)

Comment: @BruceET I tried the variable substitution/change suggested by both Did and the original poster of the question, but to no avail.