# Distribution of a sample IQR

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

> Let $X_i ∼ U(0, 1), i = 1, . . . , 20, iid$. IQR = $F^{−1}(.75)−F^{−1}(.25)$ =
>   $X_{(15)}−X_{(5)}$ in this example as n = 20.
>
> a. Find the distribution of the random variable W = IQR.
>
> b. Devise a function of this random variable such that it has
>   expectation of the length of the support of distribution. Do the same
>   thing for the range
>
> c. Consider both of these quantities from (b) as ways to guess
>   (estimate) the length of the support. Compute the relative efficiency
>   (the ratio of mean square errors, it doesn’t matter which is in the
>   numerator) of these two quantities.

So far, I've looked at an example discussing the range of a random sample from a uniform distribution, but I'm having trouble applying that example to the IQR.

Information I know for this problem includes:

$F(x)=x$ for $0<x<1$.

For order statistics: $f_k(x)= \frac{n!}{((k-1)!(n-k)!)}*{f(x)F(x)^{k-1}(1-F(x))^{n-k}}$

Bivariate joint PDF for $Y_1$ (the min) and $Y_n$ (the max) is $g(y_1,y_n)=n(n-1)[F(y_n)-F(y_1)]^{n-2} f(y_1)f(y_n)$

I've tried plugging in definitions and going from there, but I get stuck at a really difficult integral that even Wolfram can't compute, so I think I may be doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

From this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68749/difference-of-order-statistics-in-a-sample-of-uniform-random-variables) we see that $W\sim\mathsf{Beta}(15-5,20-15+5+1)$ with density
$$
f_W(t) = \frac{(20)!}{(10)!9!}t^9(1-t)^{10}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t).
$$
Since
$$
\mathbb E[W] = \int_0^1 \frac{(20)!}{(10)!9!}t^{10}(1-t)^{10}\ \mathsf dt =\frac{10}{21},
$$
letting $g(w) = \frac{21}{10}w$ yields
$$
\mathbb E[g(W)] = \frac{21}{10}\mathbb E[W] = 1.
$$

Comment: I don't know what is meant by the "range," but $W$ takes values in $(0,1)$, so this seems to be the same as the "length" of its support.